# In a Pandas dataframe, how to replace all elements x with element y?

Tags: python, pandas, search, dataframe, replace

I have a big dataframe `df`, 14 columns * 800 rows. Independently, I have file with the 2 columns (lets say with these entries):

```
car          one
bus          two
bike         three
...
```

I want to search the dataframe `df` and replace all values that appear in the left column with the corresponding elements in the same row from the right column - means, wherever i find "car" as entry in the dataframe I replace it with "one", wherever I find "bus", I replace it with "two", ect. I find the pandas dunctions .replace and .isin, but I lack the skill to combine them.

Can anyone tell me how to do the replacement in the dataframe?

---

**Suggested solution:**

read in the columns (car, bus, bike,...) and (one, two, three,...) into numpy-array-lists, e.g. (car, bus, bike,...) into list_old and (one, two, three,...) into list_new. This is doable with pandas pd.read_fwf, for example. Then one can use handy features of the pandas' .replace function:

```
df.replace(to_replace=list_old, value=list_new, inplace=True)
```

And this does the trick! Note that it also takes care of matching by index (list_old[n] replaced by list_new[n])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say, you load your file into a dataframe `df1`. Use it to generate a mapping first:

```
mapping = dict(df1[['col1', 'col2'].values)
```

Or,

```
mapping = df1.set_index('col1')['col2']
```

Now call `df.replace` on your actual dataframe, say `df2`:

```
df2.replace(mapping)
```

Alternatively, you can use `df.map` - non-matches are converted to `NaN`;

```
df2.map(mapping)
```

Comment: or `mapping = df1.set_index('col1')['col2']`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `Series` created with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.replace(df.set_index('col1')['col2'])
```

Or by `dict`:

```
df = df.replace(df.set_index('col1')['col2'].to_dict())
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['car','bus','bike'],
                   'col2':['one','two','three'],
                   'col3':['car','bike','bike']})
print (df)
   col1   col2  col3
0   car    one   car
1   bus    two  bike
2  bike  three  bike

df = df.replace(df.set_index('col1')['col2'])
print (df)
    col1   col2   col3
0    one    one    one
1    two    two  three
2  three  three  three
```